# How do I configure Strawberry Perl to run from something other than c:\strawberry?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl, vendor

I know that Strawberry Perl portable is out there for Perl 5.10.0, but so far, there is not one for Perl 5.10.1.  As a result, I'm currently doing some experimental work in getting Strawberry Perl to run from a networked location, just to see what I can get working.  I've been able to fake some of it, enough to get some Perl and some tools running, but I've not been able to figure out how to move the vendor\lib folder away from `c:\strawberry.`  I'm pretty sure my faking efforts will be for naught unless I know more about how these paths are set up.

Further reading:

[Changing Perl Config Settings](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=669488) (PerlMonks)

Comment: And amusingly enough, one of the captcha's I got was "Carp".  I do feel a bit like `croak`ing right about now...

Comment: Thank you for following up on this. The thread on PerlMonks is most interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** I have no idea, really.

Here is some speculation anyway:

Looking at [Perl::Dist::Strawberry](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CSJEWELL/Perl-Dist-Strawberry-2.01/lib/Perl/Dist/Strawberry.pm):

```
# Set the different paths
$machine->add_dimension('drive');
$machine->add_option('drive',
    image_dir => 'C:\strawberry',
);
```

So, I imagine that would be the way to build whole distributions from source to be installed in a specific location.

Neither the executables, nor the dlls have the string `strawberry` in them, so my guess is hacking away at `Config.pm` and `Config_heavy.pl` would probably get things done.

Comment: It looks like Config.pm and Config_heavy.pl will be the place to hack.  It won't get it all the way; I added a link about it in my question.